# Easing animation with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, animation

I am trying to create compass that rotate and stop at certain angle. All seems to be working fine, but since I am trying to simulate real boat's compass it would be nice to add some easing. And that is the problem that I can not overcome. 
Here is function that rotate the compass until desire course is reached ( 90 degree in this example):

```
function rotate(el,speed) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(el);
    elem.style.transform = "rotate("+degrees+"deg)";
    looper = setTimeout('rotate(\''+el+'\','+speed+')',speed);  
    if ( degrees  == 90 ){
            clearTimeout(looper);       
            }
}
```

I will appreciate any help. 
Thanks 
Robert

Comment: I would taking a look at [CSS3 transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions). You can do a a transition on the CSS property `transform` (like you are using) and one of the properties of a transition you can set is easing.

Comment: You can look at the source for jQuery's [easings](https://github.com/gdsmith/jquery.easing/blob/master/jquery.easing.js) to get some ideas, but it's somewhat complicated stuff to make an animation behave differently at different points etc.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `JQuery`, I recomend using the  [Jquery Transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) plugin which is **extremely** easy to use and it supports  animations and transitions in 2D,3D and more cool things.

This would be the code after importing the `library` using some of its built-in easing functions:

```
$('your_element_using_css_selectors').transition({ rotate: '[num_deegrees]deg' }, your_time_milis, "your_easing_function");
```

e.g.

```
$('#myComponent').transition({ rotate: '95deg' }, 700 , "easeInOutExpo");
```

Where `easeInOutExpo` is the `easing` function. check out the page link for better understanding.

Comment: Thanks Estaban, I use only java script without JQuery. One of the reason is the fact that while using js I get "current" degrees, so I can display not only position of the compass rose but also numerical degrees that change along with rotation of the compass. Can I do the same thing with  Jquery Transit?

Comment: Using JQuery Transit   does not limit the access you would have to information,  its actually the other way around.  Jquery allows you to have access to everything you would using plain-old Javascript.

Comment: Hi Esteban, I created a simple script using Jquery Transit that works: firstquestion, it looks like easeInOutElastic does not work with Jquery Transit, I used easeInOutBack that looks quite realistic.

Comment: I bilieve there's no `Bounce` function predefined,  only these: 

linear ease in out in-out snap easeOutCubic easeInOutCubic easeInCirc easeOutCirc easeInOutCirc easeInExpo easeOutExpo easeInOutExpo easeInQuad easeOutQuad easeInOutQuad easeInQuart easeOutQuart easeInOutQuart easeInQuint easeOutQuint easeInOutQuint easeInSine easeOutSine easeInOutSine easeInBack easeOutBack easeInOutBack

Comment: If none work, create your own like this:  

`$.cssEase['bounce'] = 'cubic-bezier(0,1,0.5,1.3)';`

then use :  

`$('.box').transition({ x: 0 }, 500, 'bounce');`

Answer (score -1):

yes it is really easy to rotate graphics with Jquery Transit. I created some script to ilustrate the concept:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.transit/0.9.12/jquery.transit.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#button').on('click', function () {
$('h1')
  .transition({ rotate: '180deg' }, 2000 , "easeInOutBack");
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="button">ROTATE Compass!</button>
<h1   style="position:absolute;   left:22px; top: 50px;">Rotate me</h1>
</body>  
</html>
```

I have noticed that easeInOutElastic does not work with Jquery Transit. I used easeInOutBack, but easeInOutElastic would be more realistic. In terms of getting data back from Java Script. The way I created my compass is as follow: The compass rose is rotated by 1 degree until it reaches predetermine angle in degrees. So It is very easy to display the current angle in numerical data. Obviously I can not do this in that manner with Jquery Transit or at least I do not know how. Any suggestions how to do this with Jquery? 
Thanks 
Robert